# Convert Array of URLs to array of image urls in xcode

Tags: xcode, json, ios6, nsarray, nsdate

I have an array of URLs ,I got this array as a result of JSON parsing

```
    id=[s valueForKey:@"bid"];

    title=[s valueForKey:@"btitle"];

   author=[s valueForKey:@"author"];

    price=[s valueForKey:@"price"];

    image=[s valueForKey:@"image"];
```

here for displaying that image array (array with URLs into tableviewcell) I converted that array into NSdata inside that cell-for row index() method like

NSData *imageData= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

so then i used that imagedata for displaying images in tableviewcell ..but  is there anyway to display the contents in array format so i can use it easily .

I want the same array in following format,

```
NSARRAY *a=[[ NSARRAY alloc]initWithObjects:[UIimage imagenamed:@"url1"],[UIimage imagenamed:@"url2"],nil];
```

Is there any way to convert that data format into array format?
please help me

Comment: You can convert the NSData into UIImage format and save it in an Array if I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: can u give me the code for that ???please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for storing the image data into an array...

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < [image count]; i++)
    {
        NSData *imageData= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[image objectAtIndex:i]]];
        [imagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    }
```

**EDITED:**

You have to use this code, where your getting the image urls from the dictionary but not in the cellForRowAtIndexPath() method...(*simply, before reaching the cellForRow..() method you needs to do this*)

Comment: thanks,but when i tried this inside cellfor rowatindex() function it shows exception!! :-(

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x195b012 0x1432e7e 0x190eb6a 0x190ea20 0x4b23 0x4318fb 0x4319cf 0x41a1bb 0x42ab4b 0x3c72dd 0x14466b0 0x290fc0 0x28533c 0x290eaf 0x4662bd 0x3aeb56 0x3ad66f 0x3ad589 0x3ac7e4 0x3ac61e 0x3ad3d9 0x3b02d2 0x45a99c 0x3a7574 0x3a776f 0x3a7905 0x3b0917 0x2b92 0x374157 0x374747 0x37594b 0x386cb5 0x387beb 0x379698 0x3884df9  0x37517a 0x376ffc 0x214d 0x2075 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Linq-to-ObectiveC select method](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#select), you can convert from an array of strings to an array of images as follows:

```
NSArray* images = [urls select:^id(id url) {
    return [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
}];
```